# Control Apache VirtualHost accessibility with Django application

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm developing a embedded system device which will host different Django projects.  All these are deployed with wsgi_mod mechanism, by using VirtualHosts in apache like this for two projects:

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/fkrueger/testdjango/myproj
    <Directory /home/fkrueger/testdjango/myproj>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/fkrueger/testdjango/myproj/myproj/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/fkrueger/testdjango/myproj/myproj>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


Listen 8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot /home/fkrueger/testdjango/testdb/
    <Directory /home/fkrueger/testdjango/testdb/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/fkrueger/testdjango/testdb/testdb/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/fkrueger/testdjango/testdb/testdb/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible that a third project controls the wsgi_mod to start and stop some of the hosted projects while apache is running. Like an application handler.

I found, when running the wsgi_mod in daemon mode it will recognize when changing the wsgi.py file. I could have a mock application to avoid starting the Django project. But I do not want to change files during runtime.

Is there a better way to do this?